# adding 0 as padding to numbers with decimal points in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of numbers with a decimal point.  I would like to add a 0 in front of numbers with only one integer before the decimal place while retaining the trailing 0 in values that have one.  For example `5.466` should read `05.466` and `43.770` should read `43.770`.

Here is the data

```
longM<-c(18.846, 18.906, 5.466, 11.19, 6.894, 7.578, 5.13, 53.868, 57.216, 
0.228, 41.892, 57.576, 44.19, 29.292, 16.452, 48.306, 16.224, 
28.566, 32.328, 25.908, 9.318, 7.332, 38.838, 4.812, 27.588, 
20.922, 30.804, 43.872, 7.734, 41.856, 3.222, 47.364, 5.754, 
21.792, 43.494, 50.82, 48.618, 4.524, 5.454, 48.744, 36.504, 
44.328, 38.61, 39.084, 38.52, 39.504, 4.206, 47.928, 15.996, 
42.99, 46.116, 26.496, 44.148, 40.284, 43.296, 34.248, 22.242, 
29.838, 31.38, 27.12, 22.278, 21.36, 20.142, 15.93, 54.726, 12.072, 
13.05, 11.886, 1.242, 54.42, 48.132, 42.954, 4.986, 32.604, 12.018, 
43.77, 26.172, 30.27, 39.738, 47.514, 27.012, 45.654, 35.796, 
44.52, 30.564)
```

I have tried

```
longM2<-formatC(longM,flag=0, width=6,drop0trailing=F)
```

and

```
library(stringr)
 longM22<-str_pad(longM,width=6,side="both",pad="0")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html) :

```
sprintf("%06.3f",longM)
```

e.g.

```
> sprintf("%06.3f",c(1.0, 33.4, 12.345,0.1243,12000))
[1] "01.000"    "33.400"    "12.345"    "00.124"    "12000.000"
```

The format `%06.3f` means :

- you want to pad the number using zeros
- you want to format the number using exactly 6 characters(*)
- you want 3 digits precision after the point

(*) Note that if the number is `>= 100`, more than 2 digits will be shown before the point anyway (basically breaking the format constraint).